# apply filtering to to - many relation ships

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have List of merchants who are having many products.
That is for a merchant, merchant.products will have all products of that merchant. Now my requirement is that when I search with a keyword, “car” I need to get all merchant with etchant.name having substring car will all his products and if any products have the substring “car” the associated merchant with only the respected products should be retrieved. Can this be achieved using Predicates. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Predicates form part of the solution, sure. Did you try anything? What will the results be used for? How will you use the 'partial' relationship contents?

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished with the `ANY` keyword in your predicate, which is a collection operator that will return true if at least one object in a set (the products, in this case) meet some condition (the name contains the search string). Like so:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name CONTAINS[cd] %@ OR ANY products.name CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchString, searchString]
```

Comment: This will only fetch all merchant instances, whose name matches with the key and merchants having products with name containing the key. The case when only the product name is matched, the merchant object should have only those products in its relationship.